# R Histogram Display x-axis ticks as percentages

Tags: r, histogram

I have an R histogram where I have breaks set to a constant value (`breaks=16`). How would I display the x-tick values in the histogram as a percentages rather than decimals?

I was thinking of writing over the x-axis with a custom one, but am not sure how to do this when breaks are set to a constant value.

Comment: Actually, no. I'll be more clear. The x values on my hist are -.050, 0.0, .050, etc. and I want it to display -5.0%, 0.0%, 5.0%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give us any data to work with, so I will illustrate with some bogus data.  Starting with the base x-values.

```
set.seed(2017)
dat = rnorm(500)/4
hist(dat, breaks=16)
```

[image: Wrong x-axis]

The idea is to suppress printing the x-axis and replace it with the one that you want.

```
H1 = hist(dat, breaks=16, xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=H1$breaks, labels=paste0(100*H1$breaks, "%"))
```

[image: With Percent labels]